# Automation Testing without opening browser or any UI

Tags: java, api, maven, selenium, testing

I have been doing automation testing and it is working fine. It is working like open a browser, interact with elements and execute test cases based on given conditions.

I am using Selenium Webdriver, TestNG, Java and Maven for this.

Now from seniorI got request that we perform same test cases without open browser or interact with UI. How it is possible in selenium webdriver?

They said they will provide me API, It is possible to do same using API. If yes then kindly provide a small example so that I can know more about it and will implement then.

Comment: Try searching for PhantomJS and GhostDriver, these are help ful to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried PhantomJS, HtmlUnitDriver but all have their disadvantage. I think Xvfv is the better solution, no need to change code just run your script heedlessly.
Install Xvfb

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

And use this command to run mvn script heedlessly

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1624x1068x24" mvn test
```

I hope it will help you.